# How To Use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, react-native

Can anyone explain how to use the macro `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE` from React Native to create custom react modules with a specific name that's not the class name?

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) says,

> This takes an optional argument that specifies the name that the module will be accessible as in your JavaScript code

My class name is:

```
@implementation ReactCustomService
```

But I want to rename it to:

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(@"CustomService")
```

But this doesn't work. When I do:

```
var service = NativeModules.CustomService;
```

nothing is returned. But if I did `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()`, then `NativeModules.ReactCustomService` it works fine.

Any thoughts? I also tried `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE("CustomService")`, but that doesn't work either.

I'm on react-native: 0.40.0

Answer (score 5):

pass the name without any quotation marks around, eg.

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(CustomService)
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

You just can use in your native module:

```
RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_MODULE(CustomService, ReactCustomService, NSObject)
```

And in your react-native sources:

```
var service = NativeModules.CustomService;
```